# Habilitar boton al seleccionar filas de la tabla y deshabilitar boton al no tener ninguna selecccionada

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-table

Buenos Dias, tengo una tabla y quisiera que si me selecciona algun fila se me habilite un boton y que si no hay filas seleccionada se me desabilite el boton aca dejo mi codigo

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><label>All Medications</label></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="header pull-left"><input type="button" id="btn-refill" class="btn btn-primary" value="Refill Request" onclick="Ejecutar();"/></div>
        <table data-toggle="table"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, 20]"
               data-height="340"
               data-search="true" class="table-hover table-responsive" id="tableRoomList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" id="check"></th>
                    <th data-field="name">Name</th>
                    <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
                    <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
                    <th data-field="description">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>6</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>6</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>
                <tr><td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td><td>Jorge</td><td>5</td><td>AAA</td><td>Description</td></tr>

            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                    <th data-field="name">Name</th>
                    <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
                    <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
                    <th data-field="description">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>

<script>
$('td[id="check"]').each(function () {
     var myCheck = $(this).prop('checked');
     if (myCheck) {
         estado = true;
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: disculpen el codigo javascript lo puse al final del codigo que subi, fue lo que intente y no me salio

Comment: El botón que quieres habilitar/deshabilitar es el que está dentro de <div class="header> ?

Comment: correcto ese es el boton tiene id "btn-refill"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estas usando [`Bootstrap Table`](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/).

Dicho `plugin` ofrece [distintos eventos](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/documentation/#events) a los cuales te puedes suscribir.

Lo que necesitas es buscar cuales son los eventos que se disparan al cambiar la selección de las filas (eg: `check.bs.table, uncheck.bs.table, check-all.bs.table, uncheck-all.bs.table`).

Luego debes suscribir a dichos eventos una función la cual chequee la cantidad de filas seleccionadas y en base a eso, habilitar (`disabled=false`) o deshabilitar (`disabled=true`) el boton `btn-refill`

### Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('#tableRoomList');
  $table.on('check.bs.table', toggleBtn);
  $table.on('uncheck.bs.table', toggleBtn);
  $table.on('check-all.bs.table', toggleBtn);
  $table.on('uncheck-all.bs.table', toggleBtn);
  toggleBtn();

  //

  function toggleBtn() {
    var rows = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections');
    $('#btn-refill').prop('disabled', rows.length === 0);
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title"><label>All Medications</label></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="header pull-left">
      <input type="button" id="btn-refill" class="btn btn-primary" value="Refill Request" onclick="Ejecutar();" />
    </div>
    <table data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, 20]" data-height="340" data-search="true" class="table-hover table-responsive" id="tableRoomList">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" id="check"></th>
          <th data-field="name">Name</th>
          <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
          <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
          <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" id="check"></td>
          <td>Jorge</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
          <th data-field="name">Name</th>
          <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
          <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
          <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo por que los checked a elementos td, no conocía Bootstrap Table que genial !

Comment: si estoy usando Bootstrap table esta muy bueno, gracias por todo

Comment: @RaidelFonseca, si la respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como acertada.

Comment: Perfecto gracias Marcos me funciono perfectamente